# Remove the [malicious] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

A classical meta tag, [malicious](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/malicious) needs to go.

'nuff said.

Comment: Or should we, instead of deleting it, merge into `[malware]`?

Comment: delete it, I say

Comment: Malicious could also refer to users, not just malware, so it's ambiguous anyway. I agree with @Sathya.

Comment: Yes. Currently there are just 2 questions with that tag and both can use `malware` tag instead. So deleting it and changing that 2 questions tags to `malware` will end with it.

Comment: This has been completed

Comment: @Robotnik Thank you!

Comment: @slhck - haha don't thank me, I didn't do it :) I just noticed that there were no questions remaining :P

Comment: @Robotnik Sure, but thanks for reminding anyways :) I wouldn't have checked.